# Null child in Red-black tree Java

Tags: java, red-black-tree

For the fourth rule in Red-Black rules for Red-black binary search tree(not sure if it's fourth just in my book), **Every path from the root to a leaf, or to a null child, must contain the same number of black nodes**, what exactly is a null child? As far as I understood, it's like a potential child that could be added to a node but in reality, it isn't there.

```
......................................................
                            25(black)                                                              
            20(black)                             50(red)                              
    --              --              --                 70(black)              
......................................................
```

The book says this case does not follow the red-black rules and I'm not sure why. I'd assume it has something to do with a null child. Because it looks like it satisfies all the rules. The root is black, every node is either red or black, if a node is red, its child is black. And every path from the root to a leaf contains the same number of black nodes. So how exactly does the null child make this case not follow the red-black rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path `25, 50, --` has 1 black node (25); path `25, 50, 70` has 2 black nodes (25 and 70). Normally rules for red-black trees don't make a distinction between leaves and null children; we can say that the `70` node also has two null children, and it's those which are the leaves.

Comment: Is it safe to say that the nodes with No children or One child can have null children but not the ones with TWO children?

Comment: Just think about how you would implement it. Every Node will have two references to children. If it's the bottom most node in the tree (I'd call this a leaf) it will have two null children (you might call those two leafs instead of the node they are referenced to. Depends on how you define it).

Comment: @LookAtTheBigPicture Each node has exactly two children. One or both of them can be null.